# Bug with sn-jnl affiliations. Some superscript do not show up

Tags: macros, affiliation, author-number

I am currently finalising a document that has 25+ authors and 22 related affiliations, using LaTex and the class file sn-jnl.

When declaring author names and their affiliations, I use the author command as follows:

```
\author[1]{\fnm{Forename} \sur{Surname}}
\author[11]{\fnm{Forename} \sur{Surname}}
```

And after I am done calling author names, I add affiliations as follows:

```
\affil[1]{\orgdiv{foo1}, \orgname{bar1}, \orgaddress{\city{lala1},  \country{blabla1}}}
\affil[11]{\orgdiv{foo11}, \orgname{bar11}, \orgaddress{\city{lala11},  \country{blabla11}}}
```

The problem is that, when I compile the .tex file and I obtain the pdf, the affiliation superscript next to author name does not appear for affiliation 11 and 22, but the names produced by the affil lines appear.

I believe this is due to a bug in the sn-jnl.cls file. I haven't a solution but I tried the following:

- Substituted the `\author[11]` with another non-problematic number `\author[12]`. The code compiles as expected in this case.
- Substituted the  `\author[11]` with  `\author[1,11]`. In this case both 1 and 11 appear as superscripts of the author s name!
- On the other hand, `\author[11,1]` does not produce any superscripts.

I believe that somehow Latex thinks that 11 represents two 1's and is confused as to what to show as superscript, however I am not really familiar with Latex macros etc.. so I am not sure on how to solve this.
If anyone has a solution or any hints, it would be gladly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug in the sn-jnl.cls file. In the .cls file, in lines 519 and 531, substitute
`\ifx#1`
with
`\ifx{#1}`.